# Pivot multiple aggregate columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I would like to pivot multiple aggregate columns.
This is the query:

```
SELECT DATEPART(WK, vsrv.date_entered) as WkNumber,
        COUNT(vsrv.TicketNbr) AS OpenedIssues, --total ticket count
       SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ClosedIssues, --sum of tickets with closed_flag = 1
       SUM(CASE WHEN vsrvy.Surveys_Completed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SurveysCompleted,  -- Surveys_Completed flag in view is 1
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Portal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedPortal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Email Connector' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedEmail,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedCall,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Internal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedInternal, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Chat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedChat,
       CAST(ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(3,1), (SUM(CASE WHEN Board_Name = 'Application Support' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00)/COUNT(TicketNbr)), 2) AS INT) AS PercentCallsHandledAppSup,
       CAST(ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(3,1), (SUM(CASE WHEN Board_Name = 'IT Services' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00)/COUNT(TicketNbr)), 2) AS INT) AS PercentCallsHandledITServices
FROM v_rpt_service vsrv LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_SurveysByTicket vsrvy ON vsrv.TicketNbr = Vsrvy.SR_Service_RecID  
WHERE vsrv.company_name <> 'XYZ Test Company' AND vsrv.date_entered BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
GROUP BY DATEPART(WK, vsrv.date_entered)
ORDER BY WkNumber
```

The partial results are:

```
WkNumber    OpenedIssues    ClosedIssues    SurveysCompleted    
1               2               2                     0 
2               950            938                    29
```

I would like to pivot the table to be

```
                        Wk1     Wk2    Wk3 ...  
OpenedIssues              2      950
ClosedIssues              2      938
SurveysCompleted          0      29
```

I read that I have to unpivot the table first then pivot.
I created this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT DATEPART(WK, vsrv.date_entered) as WkNumber,
        COUNT(vsrv.TicketNbr) AS OpenedIssues, --total ticket count
       SUM(CASE WHEN vsrv.Closed_Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ClosedIssues, --sum of tickets with closed_flag = 1
       SUM(CASE WHEN vsrvy.Surveys_Completed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SurveysCompletedWithConnectWise,  -- Surveys_Completed flag in view is 1
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Portal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedPortal,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Email Connector' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedEmail,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Call' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedCall,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Internal' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedInternal, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Chat' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedChat,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'Activity Capture' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedActivityCapture,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Source IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssueLoggedNotDefined,
       SUM(CASE WHEN entered_by in ('VStanizzo', 'MHoude') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssuesCallsHandledByReception,
       SUM(CASE WHEN entered_by not in ('VStanizzo', 'MHoude') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IssuesCallsHandledBySupport,
       CAST(ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(3,1), (SUM(CASE WHEN Board_Name = 'Application Support' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00)/COUNT(TicketNbr)), 2) AS INT) AS PercentCallsHandledAppSup,
       CAST(ROUND(CONVERT(decimal(3,1), (SUM(CASE WHEN Board_Name = 'IT Services' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00)/COUNT(TicketNbr)), 2) AS INT) AS PercentCallsHandledITServices
FROM v_rpt_service vsrv LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_SurveysByTicket vsrvy ON vsrv.TicketNbr = Vsrvy.SR_Service_RecID  
WHERE vsrv.company_name <> 'XYZ Test Company' AND vsrv.date_entered BETWEEN '01/01/2016' AND '10/07/2016'
GROUP BY DATEPART(WK, vsrv.date_entered)

) AS SourceTbl
UNPIVOT
(
    SvrCnts for CtnCol 
        in (OpenedIssues, ClosedIssues, SurveysCompletedWithConnectWise, IssueLoggedPortal, IssueLoggedEmail, IssueLoggedCall,
            IssueLoggedInternal, IssueLoggedChat, IssueLoggedActivityCapture, IssueLoggedNotDefined, IssuesCallsHandledByReception,
            IssuesCallsHandledBySupport, PercentCallsHandledAppSup, PercentCallsHandledITServices)
) AS UnPivotTbl
ORDER BY WkNumber
```

Now how do I pivot from here?

Comment: You should just be able to add the `PIVOT` after `UNPIVOT`, using `PIVOT (SUM(SvrCnts) FOR WkNumber IN ([1], [2], [3]...[53])) AS pvt` I would suggest however, that you let your presentation layer do the pivoting here. Something like Week number is very changeable, so you are either going to need to set up your query in the first instance for all 53 weeks, or use dynamic SQL.

Comment: I am using DynamicSQL for the pivot week.  I got the pivot to work when using hard coded values for the week number but adding the dynamic SQL is throwing an error.  I have the weeks as strings 'Week1', 'Week2', etc.  But maybe I have to change that to numbers and just use [1], etc.

Comment: I was able to get the query working by using the numbers only ([1], [2]) dynamically.  Can I order the week number?  I tried in the outside query and it is not allowed.